# Bounded nonempty countable sets necessarily contain its supremum?

Tags: real-analysis

Is this true or false? I know how to prove that finite sets contain its supremum. 
Let $A=\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb R$. Since $A$ is finite, $\max(A)$ exists (can be proved by induction). And $\max(A)=\sup(A)$. So finite sets contain its supremum.

But countable sets includes finite sets and countable how to prove a bounded countable infinite set contains its supreme. I don't think the maximum method works any more for countable infinite set. Does this has something to do with closure? need some hints please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

False: $\left\{1-\frac1n\right\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$.

Does it has something to do with closure? Yes, a closed bounded set necessarily contains its supremum, even if it is uncountable.

Comment: now i get it. thank you so much

Comment: @YunhuiShi: you're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

For example: $$\mathbb Q\cap(0,1)$$